# F# type inference in format strings

Tags: f#

How is it possible for F# to examine format strings at compile time to determine that x has type int in the following definition?

```
let foo x = sprintf "%d" x`?
```

Is this hard-coded into the language or could somebody write their own "my_print" function that uses format strings with a different syntax? For example:

```
let foo x = my_print "{integer}" x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read a bit about it in 6.4.17 ('printf' formats) [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec2.aspx), but briefly

- it's built into the language
- string literals can effectively be 'coerced' into the weird 'Format' type
- printf and friends expect a first argument of the Format type, making the coercion happen

The net result is that you can build your own printf-style functions, but must use the same %s formats, since that stuff is built-in.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://diditwith.net/2008/12/29/PrintfAndFormattingDebugOutputInF.aspx) is an example of how you can build your own printf-style functions in F#. You can't change the format specifiers (e.g. "%d"), but you can leverage the existing specifiers to build additional string formatting functions that the compiler will type check.